# Lubuntu on Acer Aspire one not booting after installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

i've installed lubuntu 16.04 on a acer aspire one d250

but after successfull installation I only got this prompt:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 121560/9707520 files, 1258806/38812672 blocks
```

I can't type anything and lubuntu dosn't start.
Whats wrong and how can I fix this?

Now I changed the bootoptions form

quiet splash -- to -- noplymouth

Now I got this screen

[image]

Comment: Have you used the "Try Ubuntu" option? Does it work OK on the laptop?

Comment: My experience has been that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (as oppose to Lubuntu) runs well on an Acer Aspire One D-250, both from the USB stick and as a dual-boot on HDD. Try downloading the 32-bit version and recreating the boot USB drive. Use one of 2 to 16 GB, but larger drives may pose problems.

Comment: What is the try ubuntu option?

Its a single installation.

Comment: When I start the netbook in recovery mode it works ... and it does normally boot

Comment: problem solved with 14.04 it works fine